# Changing airport connection preference algorithm

Tags: macbook-pro, airport

Airport connects to the network in order of preference that I have set. Is there a way to make it connect to the network that I was last connected to, instead of the one higher in the list.

For eg. I have 3 networks, in order, Wifi0, Wifi1 & Wifi2. If I am connected to Wifi1 and close the lid, open it back, it will connect to Wifi0. I want it to connect to Wifi1.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you can do this by marcopolo http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/

Answer (score 1):

You can set another location (also called configuration) in the Network preference panel. In the Location1 configuration, you only keep the Wifi1, and do the same with a Location2. (I know this isn't what you're searching for, but it's a workaround).

Comment: i don't follow. I am not seeing any option to add a location. I can only order the wireless connections